# Adjusting/compensating for strange font line height in CSS

Tags: css, fonts

I have received a font (Calibre) as an OTF file from a client to use in a web app but there's something weird with the "line height" (or what do you call this?) of the file. The actual text overflows the dom element on top and leaves a bunch of space below causing all sorts of ugliness. Is there any way of compensating for this in CSS?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I vertically align text in a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/how-do-i-vertically-align-text-in-a-div)

Answer (score -2):

It depends on the font. However, for most fonts, setting

```
div {
    height: /* your height */
    line-height: /* the same height */
}
```

will make it work. However, some fonts, like Aldrich, are positioned just a little higher than it feels they should be, so you have to increase the line-height by 0.4% or so.